# \bibdata transformed with relative path, any way to stop this?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, auxiliary-files

At some point pdflatex has started generating \bibdata entries in the .aux file with a leading ./, which causes bibtex to ignore the BIBINPUTS path. Is there any option to stop pdflatex from doing this? And if anybody knows what version this started with I would love to know because I don't think it used to do this.

FYI I opened a new question because everything I found in a search was ten or eleven years old.

Comment: it doesn't by default please show a small complete example, so people can debug

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

in both texlive2023 and texlive2024 produces an `.aux` file

```
\relax 
\bibstyle{plain}
\bibdata{references}
```

with no `./`